# Remove icon from collapsible set in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been trying to remove the icon from a collapsible set by setting the attribute `data-iconpos="none"` in the `div` that acts as the `collapsible-set`, but no luck. It would remove it but still leave some kind of shadow.

[image]

Comment: Could you post HTML code? Thanks

Comment: Make sure you remove, both the `data-icon=""` and `data-iconpos=""` parameters from the element. Shouldn't it be an <li> not a <div> you remove them from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only solution for this is using CSS, try adding a class to the collapsible such as: `class='listItemNoIcon'`

within your HTML file add this :

```
<div  class='listItemNoIcon' data-role='collapsible' data-collapsed='false'>
</div>
```

and add this to your css file:

```
.listItemNoIcon .ui-icon
{

 display: none;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Working with jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 you can also set the `data-collapsed-icon` and `data-expanded-icon` attributes to `false`.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="false" data-expanded-icon="false" data-theme="a">
     <h2>My Account</h2>

    <ul class="ui-listview mainNav" data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
        <li data-icon="carat-r"> <a href="#">Manage Account</a>

        </li>
        <li data-icon="carat-r"> <a href="#">Edit Profile</a>

        </li>
        <li data-icon="carat-r"> <a href="#">Upload Profile Picture</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnVK9/)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the above solution will hide all icons within the collapsible fieldset.

To make sure you only hide the icon in the collapsible header use this:

```
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

Since jquery mobile adds the class 'ui-collapsible-heading' to the heading inside the collapsible fieldset.

Should work until jquery mobile decides to change something ;)

Answer (score 1):

Working with JQM 1.4.0rc1, there still seem to be some trouble with this. I had to use the following Javascript logic in my PageShow event to hide the icons completely:

```
$('#MyList').find('a.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-btn-icon-right');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is the Li element for which you do not need any icon do following

```
$(<your-li-elment>).find("span.ui-icon').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon what Demnogonis wrote, `data-collapsed-icon="noicon"` and `data-expanded-icon="noicon"` in conjustion with adding the class `ui-nodisc-icon` to the collapsible parent, worked for me. Otherwise there was an empty circle leftover.

http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/icons/
Search: Removing the disc

Using JQM 1.4.5

Answer (score -1):

give your collapsible set an id and then you can do the following

```
#myId >.ui-icon
{

 display: none;

}
```

This CSS look at all elements with the class .ui-icon inside your collapsible set and sets their display to none

Answer (score -1):

You can do it either with CSS or overwrite the JQM javascript.

1. CSS

   .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-icon {
         display: none;
    }
2. overwrite the JQM
   search for this line:
   collapsedIcon = $el.jqmData( "collapsed-icon" ) || o.collapsedIcon || "plus";
   replace with: 
   collapsedIcon = ($el.jqmData("collapsed-icon") =="none")? false : (o.collapsedIcon || "plus");

and add this attribute data-collapsed-icon="none" in html like below

```
 <li data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false"  data-collapsed-icon="none" data-icon="false">
       <h3>Section 1</h3>
       <p>I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.</p>
 </li>
```

Answer (score -2):

The [jQM 1.1.1 data-attribute reference](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html) mentions that the possible values of the data-iconpos   attribute for the Collapsible set are:

> left | right | top | bottom | notext

Therefore maybe the only workaround is the solution with custom CSS.

Comment: I know how to hide them overriding CSS, but the framework says that data-iconpos="non" should work, hence my question.

Comment: The http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html data reference says that the possible values of the data-iconpos attribute are eft | right | top | bottom | notext. I updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: As of jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 (although possibly added earlier), there is now a "none" value for data-iconpos attribute. However, I found that setting it to "none" still causes the same behavior referenced by @manutenfruits - This appears to be a bug... http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible-set/